# Typescript generic class as function parameter

Tags: typescript, class, generics

I have two unrelated classes and a function that interacts with the `constructor.name` I don't want to use the `any` type. Is there a way I can write the following in a typescript way? I want `someClass` to represent any class but I'm not exactly sure how to write that.

```
class MyClass {
    //
}

class MyOtherClass {
    // 
}

const getClassName = (someClass, name = someClass.constructor.name) => {
    console.log(someClass)
    console.log(someClass.constructor.name)
}

getClassName(MyClass)
```

Comment: Likely `new (...args: any[]) => any`

Comment: You can find some OOP typings in my [article](https://catchts.com/oop-style)

Answer (score 4):

You can define the type for a class constructor, like this:

```js
type ClassConstructor<T> = {
  new (...args: any[]): T;
};

const getClassName = (someClass: ClassConstructor<any>) => {
    console.log(someClass.name)
}

getClassName(MyClass)
getClassName(MyOtherClass)
// this is a complie error: not a constructor
getClassName(() => 1)
// this is a complie error: instance - not a class
getClassName(new MyClass())
```

[Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgziA2CmB0w4EMBOAKAlAbgFC6WQggAIBZATwGFojSBvXAX30OPIoHkAXAC1lQ06JRiTEkA9BJLN83CgAdYJIcSrgI3VAFdg3EKgA8AFQB8JALwjcYsLADuJdPBdoA5hABcJZGAoBtAF1Mb2M8JjwCDW4SN1huVQgAOWQAW2UrdCh0xO9E9UgtXX0jXwpTTEtzUXFQSBgEaBA3LJAc2mJ4MDTYTFk4hI7knvRKRL6BxJT00a4+AXHcKRI+AEtSdZ8SUFSFaFXlAVQDbzAQGORt6J09A1xJoenYdCwqkgBGPuW1jdJLnb2BxIRxOJFWhV8wGUAFoSGcLtshvd4lMRnZHGMhlhMEA)

But beware, that the class-name may be different in production: i.e. when you use webpack to minify/uglify your code

Comment: It worth using inference on function arguments. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/ND2J4W)

Answer (score 0):

From the `lib.es5.d.ts` (the file with Record / Partial / etc definitions) you can see builtin definition of

```
/**
 * Obtain the return type of a constructor function type
 */
type InstanceType<T extends abstract new (...args: any) => any> = T extends abstract new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any;
```

So, the constructor is defined as

```
type Constructor<T> = abstract new (...args: any) => T;
```

And your function is

```
const getClassName = (someClass: Constructor<any>, name = someClass.constructor.name) => {
    console.log(someClass)
    console.log(someClass.constructor.name)
}
```

or

```
const getClassName = (someClass: abstract new (...args: any) => any, name = someClass.constructor.name) => {
    console.log(someClass)
    console.log(someClass.constructor.name)
}
```

---

If you want to use the class name and keep your class itself on type level, you can use Branded (oko Opaque) types:

```
type Constructor<T> = abstract new (...args: any) => T;
// I tend to name non-object subtipes camelCase
type className<T> = string & {__classNameOf: T}
// or
declare const classNameOfSymbol: unique symbol
type className2<T> = string & {[classNameOfSymbol]: T}

function getClassName<T> (someClass: Constructor<T>, name = someClass.constructor.name): className<T> {
  return name as className<T>
}
```